# How to add label on chart.js on each point

Tags: charts, chart.js

How to add label when hovered on a line graph using chart.js on each point just like on their website:

[Chart.js example usage](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-example-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sample code on the link you provided. The "datasets" are the ones that are responsible for the hovered values (to be precise the data in datasets).

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```

Edit: So the asnwer was initing the plugin like this:

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, { pointDot : true });
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing happens. Is there any css that is used in this one?

Comment: There is only a JS file which you have to include.
What browser are you using? Try using a different one. Also try initing the plugin like this:
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    pointDot : true
});

Comment: You don't specify which version you are using but there is a plugin that does this with version 2: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/